# ASP.NET Listview hiddenfield value is empty onselect

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview

i searched a lot of question, read a lot of solutions but still haven't found the one which solve the problem i'm struggling with:
my listview shows a few pictures from a directory, but sometimes i forgot to rotate a picture, there i want a button to select a item and then a button to rotate the picture shown. but i can't resolve the value in the 2 hiddenfields which hold the URL values. i get the start value and not the evaluated value:

```
Dim URLorg As HiddenField = TryCast(FotoListView.Items(FotoListView.SelectedIndex).FindControl("URLorigineel"), HiddenField)
```

**URLorg.value gives >>  "../<%# Eval("URLorigineel") %>"**

Source:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="FotoListView"    ItemPlaceholderID="PlaceHolder3"     DataSourceId='odsAvailableFotos' DataKeyNames="ID">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul>
            <div style="overflow:scroll; height:380px;">                                             <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder3" /> 
            </div> 
        </ul>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <hr />
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton1" Text="Select" CommandName="Select" BackColor="#33CCFF" BorderColor="#003399" Width="70"  CssClass="PhotoEditBtn" Height="15" />  
            <a href='../<%# Eval("URLorigineel") %>' target="_blank" id="ImageRef"><%# Eval("Caption")%><br />
                <img src='../<%# Eval("URL") %>' alt="Click to see image"  class="Rounded_image_sample" id="ImgSource" />
            </a> 
            <asp:HiddenField ID="URL" runat="server" Value='../<%# Eval("URL") %>' />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="URLorigineel" runat="server" Value='../<%# Eval("URLorigineel") %>' />
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SelectedItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <hr />
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton1" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" BackColor="#33CCFF" BorderColor="#003399" Width="70"  CssClass="PhotoEditBtn" Height="15" />  
            <asp:Label ID="dummy1" runat="server" text="     " />
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton2" Text="Rotate" CommandName="Rotate" CssClass="PhotoEditBtn" BackColor="#33CC33" Width="70" Height="15" /> 
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton3" Text="Cancel" CommandName="ANnuleer" CssClass="PhotoEditBtn" BackColor="#33CC33" Width="70" Height="15" />
            <br />
            <a href='../<%# Eval("URLorigineel") %>' target="_blank" id="ImageRef"><%# Eval("Caption")%><br />
                <img src='../<%# Eval("URL") %>' alt="Click to see image"  class="Rounded_image_sample" id="ImgSource" />
            </a> 
            <asp:HiddenField ID="URL" runat="server"  Value='../<%# Eval("URL") %>' />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="URLorigineel" runat="server" Value='../<%# Eval("URLorigineel") %>' />
        </li>
    </SelectedItemTemplate>

</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try with this code

```
Value='<%# string.Format("{0}{1}",'../',Eval("URL")) %>' 

Result :  <asp:HiddenField ID="URL" runat="server" Value='<%# string.Format("{0}{1}",'../',Eval("URL")) %>'  />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
there is a field "DataKeyNames=", in the Listview headertag, which you can set and refer to when needed.
in my case this was enough to make the serverside function work.

thanks